# How do I use Google Cloud Datastore with Ruby?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'd like to use Google Cloud Datastore from a Rails app. Any Ruby lib that would make that easy?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the official Google API Client for Ruby:

https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client

```
# Log in
google-api oauth-2-login --client-id='...' --client-secret='...' --scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"

# Start an interactive API session
google-api irb
>> ds = $client.discovered_api('datastore', 'v1beta1')
>> $client.execute(ds.lookup, {'datasetId' => '...', 'keys' => [...]})
=> # returns a response from the API
```

Comment: Note that you need both `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scopes.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be very little resources on using Datastore with Ruby, but this page is probably the best place to start:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_ruby/